# Slack Curl not working

Tags: linux, curl, redhat, libcurl, slack

A have a script that is sending messages to a slack channel perfectly.The script is placed on a test server with the following curl Version:

> curl --version
>   curl 7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
>   Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps
>   Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

When the same script is placed on the second server with the same curl version, it is displaying me the following curl message:

> curl: (35) error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm

**My code:**

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/json" \
  -X POST -d \
  '{
     "channel" : "#'"$ROOM"'",
     "username" : "'"$USERNAME"'",
     "icon_emoji" : ":'"$EMOJI"':",
     "attachments" : [
       {
         "fallback" : "'"$TITLE_1"'",
         "color" : "'"$COLOR"'",
         "fields" : [
           {
             "title" : "'"$TITLE_1"'",
             "value" : "'"$MSG_1"'"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
  }' $SLACK_URL_HOOK
```

Please help, i need to know why it is not working on the main server.

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to figure it out.
Added the -k as --none-secure message to the curl.

Now Looks like this:

```
curl -k -H "Content-type:application/json" \
  -X POST -d \
  '{
     "channel" : "#'"$ROOM"'",
     "username" : "'"$USERNAME"'",
     "icon_emoji" : ":'"$EMOJI"':",
     "attachments" : [
       {
         "fallback" : "'"$TITLE_1"'",
         "color" : "'"$COLOR"'",
         "fields" : [
           {
             "title" : "'"$TITLE_1"'",
             "value" : "'"$MSG_1"'"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
  }' $SLACK_URL_HOOK
```